# display table data in oracle apex

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

i  have  tried  to  include  oracle  express  application  to  create  a  GUI (graphical user interface) for  my  oracle  pl sql  app

**my  sql pl  script  was  a  oriental  objects data  type**
i  failed  to  create  a succes  application  oracle  apex  using  this  script

can  any  one  show  us  the  correct  way  to  display  all  tables  data  in  oracle  apex  using object  browser  or  application  page by  this  script ?

thanks

my  script  :
**create  object  types  and  their  table**

```
CREATE TYPE client_type AS OBJECT
 (num NUMBER(5), nom VARCHAR2(30), adresse VARCHAR2(30))
/
--Création de compte
CREATE TYPE compte_type AS OBJECT
 (nCompte VARCHAR2(5), solde NUMBER(10,2), dateOuv DATE, ref_Client REF client_type) 
 NOT FINAL NOT INSTANTIABLE
/
CREATE TYPE cptCourant_type UNDER compte_type 
 (nbOpCB NUMBER(5))
/
CREATE TABLE Client OF client_type
  (CONSTRAINT pk_client PRIMARY KEY (num));

CREATE TABLE CptCourant OF cptCourant_type 
  (CONSTRAINT pk_cptCourant         PRIMARY KEY (nCompte),
   CONSTRAINT nn_Courant_ref_Client CHECK (ref_Client IS NOT NULL),
   CONSTRAINT refer_Courant_Client  ref_Client REFERENCES Client)
 ;
```

**insert  data  script**

```
INSERT INTO Client VALUES
  (client_type(1, 'Albaric', 'Pont Vieux  - Vielle Toulouse'
             ));



INSERT INTO Client VALUES
  (client_type(3, 'Miranda', 'Antipolis - Nice'));

INSERT INTO Client VALUES
  (client_type(4, 'Payrissat', 'Salas - Ramonville St Agne'
            ));

INSERT INTO Client VALUES
  (client_type(5, 'Vielle', 'INRA - Auzeville Tolosane',
           ));

--Insertion des comptes

INSERT INTO CptCourant VALUES
    (cptCourant_type('CC1', 4030, '01-02-2001',
     (SELECT REF(cli) FROM Client cli WHERE cli.num = 1), 509) 
    );

INSERT INTO CptCourant VALUES
    (cptCourant_type('CC2', 3000, '15-02-2002',
     (SELECT REF(cli) FROM Client cli WHERE cli.num = 1), 0) 
    );

INSERT INTO CptCourant VALUES
    (cptCourant_type('CC3', 460, '13-05-2000',
     (SELECT REF(cli) FROM Client cli WHERE cli.num = 4), 678
    ) 
    );
```

Comment: Whatever query that returns a set of rows/columns. And use a PL/SQL API instead of a automated process.

Comment: can  you  saw  me  how  to  do  it  please  ..i  am  not inderstanded your  response

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how to run a SQL statement using Objects
https://oracle-base.com/articles/8i/object-types

Here how to use PL/SQL with Objects
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/objects.htm

So for your page process on submit, use a table API
https://jeffkemponoracle.com/2016/02/12/apex-api-call-a-package-for-all-your-dml/

As for specifics on how to display nested data, well that's up to your requirements and desires, unknown to us.